# Jqgrid columns are not editable in firefox pl help me

Tags: firefox, jqgrid

The jqgrid is working fine in chrome but it is not working fine in Firefox, in Firefox I am not able to edit the rows, even drop down is not working, if I use tab then only it is working fine, here is my code:

```
    var l = $("#variablesGrid");
    l.jqGrid({
        datatype: "local",
        data: e,
        colNames: ["Data Type", "Is not Array", "Field Name", "Action"],
        colModel: [{
                name: "dataType",
                index: "dataType",
                width: 50,
                editable: true,
                edittype: "select",
                editoptions: {
                    value: r
                },
                align: "left"
            }, {
                name: "isArray",
                index: "isArray",
                width: 17,
                editable: true,
                formatter: "checkbox",
                edittype: "checkbox",
                editoptions: {
                    value: "true:false"
                },
                align: "center"
            }, {
                name: "fieldName",
                index: "fieldName",
                width: 40,
                editable: true,
                align: "left",
                editrules: {
                    custom: true,
                    custom_func: f
                }
            }, {
                name: "act",
                index: "act",
                width: 10,
                sortable: false
            }],
        rowNum: 1e5,
        pager: "#variablesPager",
        gridview: true,
        rownumbers: true,
        sortname: "invdate",
        viewrecords: true,
        sortorder: "desc",
        caption: "Variables",
        editurl: "clientArray",
        width: 900,
        height: 250,
        loadComplete: function () {
            var e = this;
            setTimeout(function () {
                updatePagerIcons(e);
                enableTooltips(e)
            }, 0)
        },
        gridComplete: function () {
            var e = jQuery(o).jqGrid("getDataIDs");
            for (var t = 0; t < e.length; t++) {
                var r = e[t];
                ce = '<div title="" style="float:left;margin-left:5px;" class="ui-pg-div ui-inline-del" id="jDeleteButton_12" onclick="BPMProcessPropertiesModule.deleteGridRow(\'' + r + "','" + n + '\');" onmouseover="jQuery(this).addClass(\'ui-state-hover\');" onmouseout="jQuery(this).removeClass(\'ui-state-hover\');" data-original-title="Delete selected row"><span class="ui-icon ui-fa fa-trash"></span></div>';
                jQuery(o).jqGrid("setRowData", e[t], {
                    act: ce
                })
            }
        },
        onSelectRow: function (e) {
            if (s === false) {
                if (e !== t) {
                    if(t === undefined){
                        t = e;
                    }

                    var r = jQuery(o).jqGrid("getCell", t, "fieldName");
                    if (r !== false && r != "undefined") {
                        if (r.indexOf('name="fieldName"') > 0) {
                            r = $("#" + t + "_fieldName").val();
                            n = false;
                            if (r === "" || r === " " || MDBPMUtils.hasSpaces(r)) {
                                n = true;
                                l.jqGrid("saveRow", t);
                                $("#" + t + "_fieldName").focus();
                                jQuery("#variablesGrid").jqGrid("setSelection", t)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if (n === false) {
                if (e !== t) {
                    if (t) {
                        l.jqGrid("saveRow", t)
                    }
                    t = e
                }
                l.jqGrid("editRow", e, true);
                return true
            }
        }
    });
```